# Variavel nao definida

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

O meu código dá-me erro numa definição de uma variável mas penso que esteja declarada a variável `bits_rx`, esta variável tem como finalidade o resultado da conversão:

```
while(1):

while not radio.available(0):
    time.sleep(1 /100)

receivedMessage= []
radio.read(receivedMessage, radio.getDynamicPayloadSize())


string = ""

for n in receivedMessage:
    string += chr(n)
    ascii=convert_to_ascii(string)
    ascii_aux2=np.array(ascii)
    bits_rx=dec_to_bin(ascii)
    print("Bits(recebidos)=",' '.join('{:04b}'.format(n) for n in ascii))
    erros=np.sum(np.array((bits-bits_rx)!=0, dtype=int))
    print("Erros= ", erros)
```

Comment: Que linguagem é essa ? creio que seja `Python` então de uma olhada nessa resposta: [O que tem de errado com a identação desse código python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/170359/60376)

Comment: sim é python,  mas bits_rx pode-se declarar assim não pode?

Comment: sim, verifica a identação

Comment: já dei volta á indentação e dá sempre o mesmo erro!!

Comment: Tem dois `while` no mesmo nível de indentação ali.

Comment: como posso voltar a editar e por o código certo? como eu o tenho no IDLE dos Raspberry

Comment: Abaixo do código na pergunta tem as *tags* e abaixo das *tags* tem a opção editar, ou [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/241641/edit)

Comment: ok, obrigado, já coloquei o código, o erro continua a dar-me

Comment: Qual a mensagem de erro completa e a linha?

Comment: ja encontrei o problema de estar a dar erro, foi um dos emissores que se estragou  e daí dar erro, agradeço a ajuda disponibilizada na mesma.